# Issue to center elements horizontally in a container

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to get my 6 circles centered horizontally to the middle of the page.
I tried to put them in a `.middle` `DIV` with `display: block` and auto margins but no success - looks like they are aligned to the left side of .middle

http://jsfiddle.net/376wC/

Many thanks for your help

```
.middle {
    width: 980px;
    height: 600px;;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/376wC/3/)

This is the required change:

```
.middle {
    width: 780px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I believe he wants 3 circles in a row

Comment: Using inline blocks with 980px width will make 4 circles in a row. I've tried it already

Comment: OK thanks guys! So only solution is, as suggested by Itay to change the width of my container to make it match the width of my 3 circles + margins? No way to center the elements without playing with the width of the container?

Comment: Do you have to have 3 elements in a row?

Comment: Yes, 3 elements by row. Thanks

Comment: You're already setting the width of the wrapper to 980, so I can't see what's wrong with changing it to 780px etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline-block`, you need to adjust the size of the circle + margins so that only 3 will fit on a row.  So in my example, the circle is 10px wider and taller and there are 4 extra pixels in between each circle:

http://jsfiddle.net/376wC/5/

Also, you can get rid of the `circle_5px_marging` class and just put equal left and right margin on the circles (see my example).